Unable to get queryParams in a module component (Angular)
Kind of new to Angular (17)
This is my app structure
--app.routing.modules.ts
--app.component.ts
------module1.routing.module
-------------module2.routing.module
-------------module2.component.ts
----------------------------componentY.component.ts
app.routing.modules.ts ---> loads other module:
{
    path: 'module1',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/module1/module1.module').then(m => m.Module1)
}

And module1's routing:
module1.routing.module.ts ---> loads another module
{
    path: 'module2',
    loadChildren: () => import('./modules/module2/module2.module').then(m => m.Module2)
}

Now in module1, I have a component (componentX that opens a new tab and passes and ID via queryParam:
module1/components/componentX.component.ts
navigate(p_id : number){
    
    id = "call from API"
    const url = this.router.serializeUrl(this.router.createUrlTree(
      ['/module2/module2-view'], { queryParams: {id: id}}
    ));
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }

I have created a component for this module, my problem is that when the component for moduel2 is loaded, it does not get the queryParams:
module2.component.ts
ngOnInit(): void {
    var id= this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('d_id') "--> this is null"
  }

It is not until I load another component (componentY) from component2.routing.module.ts that the queryParam is registered.
I've tried creating a services and updating them from componentX.component.ts as well from within the module (componentY.component.ts)  and sending observables and call them in all lifecylce functions that angular offers but no dice. It seems like the router loads the module component before acknowledging the url or anythying else?
someService.ts
export class SomeService{

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  id= this.messageSource.asObservable();

    constructor(){}

    updateId(id: any){
        this.messageSource.next(id)
      }
}

module2.component.ts
export class model2Component OnInit{

  id: number;

  constructor(private someService: SomeService){
  }
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.someService.id.subscribe(id => this.id = id)
  }

This is probably my fault for a messy project structure but I am kind of lost at the moment. Is there any solution and/or resources that I can use to solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

please share module 2 routing also

Your code to perform the navigation looks very complicated. Why don't you simply call this.router.navigate(['/module2/module2-view'], { queryParams: {id: id}})?

This is because the component Y is where the query param exists. You can easily resolve this by using firstChild, which is component Y (first child) of module2 (parent).
One more thing to note is that you are passing id but you are reading d_id, which is incorrect.
Also since the child gets the query params, it's better to use subscribe instead of snapshot here.
module2.component.ts
  id!: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route?.firstChild?.queryParamMap?.subscribe((params) => {
        this.id = params.get('id') || '';
    });
  }

